# VB.net - JSON parse - Newtonsoft

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am having a troble parsing JSON using vb.net with Newtonsoft Json library.

My JSON Data is as follows :

```
{
"Result":"Success",
"UserID":"johns",
"Password":null,
"Locked":"False",
"Comment":"",
"LastLoggedOn":"11/9/2013 9:14:17 PM",
"NumFailedAttempts":"1",
"FirstName":"John",
"LastName":"Smith",
"MessageNum":"UA-000",
"MessageText":"Authorisation successful"
}
```

My code is as follows :

```
Dim a As saLoginResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of saLoginResponse)(strJSONEncode)
            Response.Write(a.ToString)

Response.Write(a.MessageText)
```

This does not produce any output.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `saLoginResponse` class is defined like the following, and your `strJSONEncode` string contains the JSON data you posted in your question, your code should work fine.

```
Public Class saLoginResponse
    Public Property Result As String
    Public Property UserID As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property Locked As Boolean
    Public Property Comment As String
    Public Property LastLoggedOn As String
    Public Property NumFailedAttempts As String
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property MessageNum As String
    Public Property MessageText As String
End Class
```

Demo:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim json As String = _
    "{" + _
    """Result"":""Success""," + _
    """UserID"":""johns""," + _
    """Password"":null," + _
    """Locked"":""False""," + _
    """Comment"":""""," + _
    """LastLoggedOn"":""11/9/2013 9:14:17 PM""," + _
    """NumFailedAttempts"":""1""," + _
    """FirstName"":""John""," + _
    """LastName"":""Smith""," + _
    """MessageNum"":""UA-000""," + _
    """MessageText"":""Authorisation successful""" + _
    "}"

    Dim a As saLoginResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of saLoginResponse)(json)

    Debug.WriteLine(a.MessageText + " for " + a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName)

End Sub
```

Output in debug window:

```
Authorisation successful for John Smith
```

Comment: Cheers Brian. Yes, my class is defined just the way you mentioned and my json string has the data. I've validated the json data http://jsonlint.com/. I believe I've exactly similar code of yours but it is not producing the output. a.* is empty.

Comment: What happens if you run the above test code in a new project?  Does that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. 

I've two codes running at the moment; one at client side and other at server side. As ususal, client sends user id and password and server responds to it with above mentioned json. Both are two separate projects running on two different computers. Both does not parse anything.